# What is meant by a dispersion relation when complex integration in the Cutkosky rules' derivation or the computation of form factors $F(q^2)$ is used?

Tags: waves, terminology, s-matrix-theory, dispersion

In the context of calculations of loop diagrams with Cutkosky-rules very often the concept of *dispersion relation* is mentioned. For instance this technique is used in Vol. 4 of Landau-Lifshitz for the computation of the polarization tensor in paragraph 110.  It also exists a note of B.A.Kniehl "Dispersion Relations in Loop Calculations" hep-ph/9607255 that is devoted to the subject and uses as an example the computation of the photon vacuum polarization.

I will give here as an example the integral representation of the photon self-energy tensor(also to be found in Peskin& Schroeder):

$$ \Pi_{\mu\nu} = \Pi(k^2)\left(g_{\mu\nu} - \frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}\right)$$

defined in Landau-Lifshitz paragraph 101 and further discussed in paragraph 108:
There the function $\Pi(t)$ is represented as an integral along a branch cut:

$$\Pi(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\rho(t') dt}{t-t' +i\epsilon}$$

where $\rho(t)$ is called the spectral density function. More below it can be found the the spectral density function can be expressed by the imaginary part of $\Pi(t)$:

$$Im(\Pi(t)) = -\pi \rho(t)$$

so that one can write:

$$\Pi(t) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{Im(\Pi(t')}{t'-t-i\epsilon} dt'$$

This formula is quoted by Landau & Lifshitz as *dispersion relation*.
Actually, similar formulas can be found in more modern books as Peskin& Schroeder in the sections on the optical theorem and Cutkosky rules, however, the concept  *dispersion relation* is not mentioned.

Elder books like the 2nd volume of Bjorken & Drell dedicate a whole chapter of 75 pages on the subject. They start talking about impinging and scattered wave amplitudes (but not about a relation between frequency and the wave vector)  and
mention at the end of the chapter's first paragraph the Kramer-Kronig relations.

I even found the  concept   *dispersion relation* mentioned in the A.Chao's book on "Physics of collective beam instabilities in High-Energy Accelerators" in section 5.2 when the author discusses the damping effect (also called Landau damping) of a whole ensemble of particles undergoing oscillations driven by wake fields if the oscillation frequency of the particle ensemble has spectral density $\rho(\omega)$ (different from a delta function), i.e. particles can oscillate at different frequencies. For a consistent oscillatory motion a self-consistency condition has to be fulfilled:

$$ 1 = - \frac{N r_0 {\cal {W}}}{2\omega_\beta \gamma T_0}\left[ P.V. \int \frac{\rho(\omega)}{\omega-\Omega}d\omega + i \pi \rho(\Omega)\right]$$

which Chao also calls a *dispersion relation*. ${\cal{W}}$ stands for the wake field, the rest are some normalizing factors which are here of little interest.

I absolutely see the similarity in the problems mentioned, however, why would one call such a relation *dispersion relation* ?
I would call such a relation as corollary of Cauchy's integral theorem, or Hilbert transform, or Kramer-Kronig relation, but why  *dispersion relation* ?
Actually, on Wikipedia a *dispersion relation* is defined as relation between frequency and wavelength respectively wave vector.
So actually I my question is mainly about terminology. But I guess there is some physics behind why this type of relations got the name *dispersion relation*.

But it seems that nowadays this technique is a kind of old-fashioned as it was used a lot in S-matrix theory (bootstrap etc.) which seems to have only a few adepts today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a particularly deep reason here, even though it's hard to prove a negative. Here's a story of how I imagine this happened:

You are correct that these relations are what we would today call [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations), but the place where physicists, especially early quantum theorists, most likely knew the concept of Kramers-Kronig relations *from* is from the notion of complex refractive indices, where it relates the *absorption* and *dispersion* to each other, and one form of the Kramers-Kronig relations for optics says that
$$ n(\omega) = 1 + \frac{c}{\pi}\int \frac{\alpha(\omega')}{\omega'^2 - \omega^2} \mathrm{d}\omega'$$
for $n(\omega)$ the refractive index and $\alpha(\omega)$ the absorption coefficient. This is a dispersion relation since it's an equation for the refractive index and it does look a lot like the equations you've quoted if we squint, and so the name probably stuck to the HEP application of Kramers-Kronig relations that you have found even though they are not literally related to dispersion of waves.

Additionally, Kramers' and Kronig's original work *was* specifically about this dispersion relation and not about general properties of complex functions (which is also why the Wiki article on the Kramers-Kronig relations reminds us that mathematicians might call the more general version for complex functions the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem instead). Since naming things after people tends to take a while to become universally accepted, it seems perfectly plausible to me that the early theorists who named the HEP versions "dispersion relations" learned about these results before the name "Kramers-Kronig relations" was well-established (Kramers and Kronig published their results independently in the late 1920s).

Answer (score 0):

They are called *dispersion relations* because they are examples of the [Kramers-Kronig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) Relations that link the real and imaginary parts of the refractive index of a material. And of course it the frequency dependent refractive index that causes a prism to *disperse* a light beam into its component colours.